# Book about clothoids

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, curves

I'm looking for a good book (or a reliable website) about **clothoids** (aka Euler's spiral). I need a proper definition, the derivation of the curve and parametrization using Fresnel integrals. I only found this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CornuSpiral.html but I need something more in-depth and I can't find Bernoulli's Opera. Any other suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need to to know about Euler's spiral? I have several books on curves and spirals and it never warrants more than a page. The Wiki page has some interesting information about it. As for the Fresnel parameterization, this can be be expressed in a single closed-form equation in the complex plane.

Comment: @Cye Waldman I need a bibliography for my thesis (and I prefer not to use Wikipedia). Every book you could suggest about curves and spirals could be useful even if there are not too many pages about clothoids. I need its definition, some formulas (curvature, natural equation etc..) and how it is obtained. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of books that I have with some discussion, albeit brief, of the Euler/Cornu spiral (or clothoid).

Frank Oliver et al., *NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions*, Cambridge, 2010.

Eric Weisstein, *CRC Encyclopedia of Mathematics*, CRC Press, Chapman & Hall, 2003.

Philip Davis, *Spirals: from Theodorus to Chaos*, A K Peters, 1993.

J Dennis Lawrence, *A Catalog of Special Plane Curves*, Dover, 1972.

Davin von Seggern, *CRC Standard Curves and Sufraces*, CTC Press, 1993.

My favorite equation for the Cornu spiral spiral is the compact complex form that incorporates the two Fresnel integrals, i.e.,

$$
x\left( t \right) =C\left( t \right)=\int_{0}^{t}{\cos \left( \tfrac{\pi }{2}{{u}^{2}} \right)du} \\ 
y\left( t \right) =S\left( t \right)=\int_{0}^{t}{\sin \left( \tfrac{\pi }{2}{{u}^{2}} \right)du} \\ 
  \\ 
\begin{align}
 z\left( t \right)&= C\left( t \right)+i\,S\left( t \right)=\int_{0}^{t}{{{e}^{i\tfrac{\pi }{2}{{u}^{2}}}}du} \\ 
 & =\frac{1+i}{2}\text{erf}\left( \frac{1-i}{2}\sqrt{\pi }\cdot t \right)  
\end{align}
$$

Finally, it's worth noting that the Cornu spiral is a special case of the more general polynomial spiral developed by

Dillen, F. (1990).  "The Classification of Hypersurfaces of a Euclidean Space with Parallel Higher Order Fundamental Form,"  Mathematische Zeitschrift,  203: 635-643. (You should be able to find this article online.)

and also shown [here](http://web.calstatela.edu/curvebank/waldman4/waldman4.htm).

Comment: Thank you very much! It would be very useful!

Comment: Don't be shy about giving credit where credit is due.